# Error: Could not find or load main class backup

Tags: hadoop, hbase, backup, restore

I have setup a Hbase on top of hadoop in my linux system. I creates a sample table in hbase shell and its working fine. However, when I try to run backup command I am getting an error in the terminal as follows:

```
> hbase backup create full hdfs://localhost:8020/data/backup
> Error: Could not find or load main class backup

OR

> hbase backup help
> Error: Could not find or load main class backup
```

I have installed apache Hadoop 2.7.3 and HBase 2.1.4. The Hbase is of Apache and not of Cloudera or Hortonworks.

I see that in the docs (http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_backup_and_restore_commands), hbase command can be used. Please help here.